# Does dnf work with all the latest data installed/updated got through yum?

Tags: fedora, package-management, yum, dnf

Through `Virtual Box` was installed `Fedora Workstation` **36**. It for experimental purposes.

About package/repository management there are two options `yum` and `dnf` where the latter is preferred over the former. For academic purposes `yum` was used and after to read some tutorials was *installed* some packages through `yum`, therefore:

```
sudo yum install <packagename>
```

and later - with 1 day of difference - the following set of commands were executed:

```
     yum check-update
sudo yum update
     yum clean all
```

With `yum update` about of 1GB of software was installed/updated according the case. And with `yum clean all` about 54 files were removed - of course according with that specific update - so it would vary in other point of time.

Now I want work with `dnf`

**Question**

- Does `dnf` work with all the latest data installed/updated got through `yum`?

For this specific case, about the 1GB of software got.

**Extra questions**

- Can `dnf` be used in peace to install/remove/update with all the *same **previous*** install/remove/update interaction of yum?
- Can `dnf` be used in peace to install/remove/update with all the *same **future*** install/remove/update interaction of yum? - therefore, be able use interchangeable both commands in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> About package/repository management there are two options yum and dnf where the latter is preferred over the former.

No, actually there is only DNF now -- starting with [Fedora 31](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Changes/Retire_YUM_3), `yum` is no longer available in Fedora, and `/usr/bin/yum` is only a symlink to `/usr/bin/dnf-3` (`/usr/bin/dnf` also points there, `3` in this context means Python 3 version of DNF) so there is no difference between using `yum` and `dnf`.

Note that `yum` package is still available but contains only the symlink and man page.

Comment: In your link provided does not appear the `/usr/bin/dnf-3` term - I am going check out

Comment: There's nothing special about that, `/usr/bin/dnf` is also symlink to `/usr/bin/dnf-3`. This is just to distinguish between Python 3 version of DNF (`python3-dnf` provides `/usr/bin/dnf-3`) and Python 2 version (`python2-dnf` used to provide `/usr/bin/dnf-2` on older versions of Fedora).